# initialize owl carousel on click function of tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using tab structure with owl slider and title but as the user wanted unique url of each tab clicked, I changed that into click function. Here, I am unable to process the slider.It just won't work.
HTML:

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li class="active" id="chhimi-gurung">
      <a href="#tab-0" data-toggle="tab" rel="chhimi-gurung">Chhimi Gurung</a>
   </li>
   <li class="" id="subha-shrestha">
      <a href="#tab-1" data-toggle="tab" rel="subha-shrestha">Subha Shrestha                        </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content" >
    <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="tab-0">
        <h3>Chhimi Gurung</h3>
        <div class="owl-carousel team-image-slider" id="team-image-slider-0">
            <img src="uploads/images/team/profile-4.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="uploads/images/team/profile-3.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-1">
        <h3>Subha Shrestha</h3>
            <div class="owl-carousel team-image-slider" id="team-image-slider-1">
                <img src="uploads/images/team/profile-1.jpg" alt="" />
                <img src="uploads/images/team/profile-2.jpg" alt="" />
                <img src="uploads/images/team/profile-3.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
var $owl = $('.team-image-slider');
$(document).on("click", "ul#myTab li a", function() {
    var slug = $(this).attr("rel");
    var current_url = url.substring(0,url.lastIndexOf("/"));
    var tabId = $(this).attr("href").split("-")[1];
    $owl.trigger('destroy.owl.carousel');
    $owl.html($owl.find('.owl-stage-outer').html()).removeClass('owl-loaded');
    $("#team-image-slider-"+tabId).owlCarousel({
       autoplay: true,
       autoplayTimeout: 5000,
       items: 1,
       nav: true,
       smartSpeed: 500,
    });
    history.pushState(null, null,  current_url + '/' + slug);
})
```

How am I to solve this? Any help/suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution for the problem. The carousel issue is due to tab hide and show. So added timeout function for initializing the carousel.

```
$(document).on("click", "ul#myTab li a", function() {
    var slug = $(this).attr("rel");
    var current_url = url.substring(0,url.lastIndexOf("/"));
    var tabId = $(this).attr("href").split("-")[1];

    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#team-image-slider-"+tabId).owlCarousel({
            autoplay: true,
            autoplayTimeout: 5000,
            items: 1,
            nav: true,
            smartSpeed: 500,
        });
    }, 200);

    history.pushState(null, null,  current_url + '/' + slug);
})
```